# error in STL sort function with Compare function

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

i try to sort a vector which element-type is a class like following:

```
void sort_test() {
    class A{
    public:
        A(float x, float y, float z):score_(x),rerank_score_(y),ranking_score_(z) {};
        float score_;
        float rerank_score_;
        float ranking_score_;
    };
    using A_ptr = std::shared_ptr<A>;
    auto CompareA_ptr = [](A_ptr x, A_ptr y) {
        if (x == nullptr && y != nullptr) {
            return false;
        } else if (x == nullptr && y == nullptr) {
            return false;
        } else if (x != nullptr && y == nullptr) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (x->rerank_score_ > y->rerank_score_) {
                return true;
            } else if (x->rerank_score_ < y->rerank_score_) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (x->score_ > y->score_) {
                    return true;
                } else if (x->score_ < y->score_) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return x->ranking_score_ >= y->ranking_score_;
                }
            }
        }
        };
    std::vector<A_ptr> X;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        X.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(A(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)));
    }
    std::sort(X.begin(), X.end(), CompareA_ptr);
 
}
int main(){
    sort_test();
    return 0;
}
```

I run the code in Xcode and get the Xcode error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"in memory.cpp:
[image]

I found that the code runs correctly when the vector size is less than 7, and an error is reported when the vector size is greater than 7. It bothers me a lot.
Appreciate for any reply.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing your code in Visual Studio revelas that `CompareA_ptr` doesn't define a *strict weak ordering* as required for a [comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). This causes undefined behaviour.

The culprit seems to be

```
return x->ranking_score_ >= y->ranking_score_;
```

where `>=` should be changed to `>`

```
return x->ranking_score_ > y->ranking_score_;
```